# find $n$ so $n/k$ is a $k$th power, $k=2,3,5$.

Tags: number-theory

Find a natural number n, in canonical form, such that:

$n/2=a^2$

$n/3=b^3$

$n/5= c^5$

for some a,b and c (natural numbers).

Comment: Write $n=2a^2=3b^3=5c^5$ and try to get information on $a,b,c$.

Comment: I did it, but can't solve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n=2^{15}3^{10}5^{6}$$

(Method: assuming the number is of the form $2^x3^y5^z$, you need $x$ to be divisible by $3\cdot5=15$, but to be $1\pmod2$, $y$ to be divisible by $2\cdot5=10$, but also be $1\pmod3$, and $z$ to be divisible by $2\cdot3=6$ but also be $1\pmod5$).

Answer (score 2):

Attempt an $n$ of the form $n = 2^x 3^y 5^z$.

You have $n/2 = 2^{x-1} 3^y 5^z$ as a square, so $x \equiv 1 (\bmod 2),\;  y \equiv z \equiv 0 (\bmod 2).$

Analogously, $x \equiv z \equiv 0 (\bmod 3)$, $y \equiv 1 (\bmod 3)$ and

$x \equiv y \equiv 0 (\bmod 5)$, $z \equiv 1 (\bmod 5)$.

The Chinese remainder theorem guarantees that you will find such natural numbers $x,y,z$.

Comment: why n has no other factors besides 2,3,5 n=2^x*3^y*5^z*more factors?.

Comment: @user1932595 Sure, it can have more factors. You could multiply a $7^{30}$ onto $n$ and it would still work.

Comment: ok, thank u. In  The Chinese remainder theorem there is one X we look for and here there is x,y,z....

Comment: Do it separately; here, $x \equiv 1 (\bmod 2)$, $x \equiv 0 (\bmod 3)$, $x \equiv 0 (\bmod 5)$ is solved by $x \equiv 15 (\bmod 30)$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take $n=2^{15}3^{10}5^{6}\lambda^{30},\lambda\in{N}$

Reason for taking $\lambda^{30}$ is $30=lcm(2,3,5)$

$15=2k_1+1=3k_2=5k_3$

$10=2l_1=3l_1+1=5l_3$

$6=2d_1=3d_2=5d_3+1$

Now I think the reason is clear.

Comment: It would help if you could elaborate some on how you came up with this. Regards

Comment: why you chose λ^30,λ∈N?

Comment: Now I have edited it @user1932595

Comment: @Amzoti i have clarified my choice....

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: great +1. Regards